# cannot import scipy.signal.convolve2d

Tags: python, scipy, anaconda

I installed Anaconda and was trying to use its convolve2d method in scipy.convolve2d,

but as I import that module: 
    'import scipy.signal.convolve2d'

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-e2463eecf22b> in <module>()
----> 1 import scipy.signal.convolve2d

ImportError: No module named convolve2d
```

which really confuses me. I have just installed the latest Anaconda and it worked for other modules I used like matplotlib.pyplot. How can I install the module for convolve2d

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try instead:

```
from scipy.signal import convolve2d
```

Comment: Thank you KronoS! Why is that import scipy.signal.convolve2d does not work?

Comment: @diodeBucks yes.  convole2d isn't a module.  It's probably a function or class.